# Class reference for a Java inner class

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

Is there a way to refer to **any** inner class?

I would like to specify a return type compatible with an inner class e.g.

```
Class<OuterClass.*> some_method();
```

I understand this syntax is invalid.  Is there a way to express this?

I know I can't use something like `Class<? extends OuterClass>` because an inner class doesn't extend an outer class.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It wouldn't add any type-safety.

Comment: Yes, you can make an inner class extending an outer class, can't you?

Comment: The class being inner is just a matter of where it's defined. You might as well ask for a way to bound a type to a package.

Comment: my question would be, why eclipse asks to import inner class? `class OuterClass<T extends InnerClass>{public static class InnerClass{}}`, the fix is that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12072708/1422630)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can refer to specific inner classes, at least:

```
<T extends OuterClass.InnerClass> Class<T> some_method()
```

Besides that, what would you gain by returning an object of *any* inner class? That would be comparable to returning any object plus the fact that the inner instance has a special relation to the outer instance. However, you'd probably not be able to directly use that special relation anyways.

Edit:

As others pointed out already `InnerClass` might be a super class extended by other inner classes. This would allow you to return *any* class, that extends that class.

If you'd use an interface, you aren't restricted to *inner* classes only, since for this restriction you'd need non-static inner interfaces. However, inner interfaces are static by default.

Comment: I think static inner classes are available only

Comment: @EugenMartynov no, you can use non-static inner classes as well.

Comment: but `InnerClass` does not extend `InnerClass`, this will not be applicable for other inner classes of `OuterClass`, I think i.e. what OP wants

Comment: `Class<OuterClass.*>` means any inner class of `OuterClass`

Comment: @Nandkumar that's true, but `InnerClass` could be an interface as well. The point is: it's not possible without implementing a special interface or extending another inner class, this is not possible. As I understood the OP the question was whether it was possible to declare _any_ inner class _without_ using special markup on the classes themselves.

Comment: @Nandkumar additionally, using an interface would not restrict you to _inner_ classes of `OuterClass`. You could return any other class that implements that interface as well. This might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather define an (inner) interface, let all inner class implement it, and then :

```
Class<OuterClass.MyInterface> someMethod();
```

This would be more type secure than trying to refer to any inner class. And you wouldn't have any problem the day you need another inner class for another usage, or the day you decide to extract a class.

Comment: Unfortunately, inner interfaces are not supported. It would have to be an inner base class.

Comment: @Thomas what do you mean "inner interfaces are not supported" ? They're commonly used and are very useful for defining callbacks.

Comment: @dystroy you're right. My own test example fooled me, inner interfaces of inner classes are not supported. :) - Additionally, inner interfaces can be implemented by other classes as well, removing the need for them to be _inner_ interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. Just as you cannot reference packages with wildcards:

```
Class<com.example.*> some_method();
Class<com.example.?> some_method();
```

The use cases for such declarations would be so limited, it just wouldn't make it into the JLS. Note, you cannot use such "location match types" outside the scope of generics either. E.g. you cannot declare:

```
void some_method(OuterClass.*  argument);
void some_method(com.example.* argument);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define marker interface and Implement it by Inner class.

```
<T implements CustomMarkerInterface> Class<T> some_method()
```

So this would be applicable to all inner classes of `OuterClass`

```
public class Outer {

    public class Inner implements CustomMarkerInterface{

    }

    public class Inner1 implements CustomMarkerInterface{

    }

    public class Inner2 implements CustomMarkerInterface{

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Class<InnerClass>` is allowed in java. Are you looking for something specific?

```
public class Client
{
interface InnerType
{
}
public class InnerClass implements InnerType
{
}
public Class<? extends Client.InnerType> test()
{
    return InnerClass.class;
}

}
```